# Matplotlib - Tuning color parameters for spectrograms

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, spectrogram

I am tuning color settings of `matplotlib` images, but I am not sure which parameters should I toggle.

Currently, my image looks like this:

[image]

But I would like it to be like this:

[image]

As shown, the whole color settings look darker and blur.

I've tried many `cmap` settings but seems didn't work out.

Can anyone give me some advice? Or can someone suggest better combinations for `spectrogram` plotting?

---

About `interpolation` parameters. I've compared different outcomes but couldn't see the difference.

```
plt.imshow(im, interpolation = 'bilinear', vmin = 50, vmax = 250)
```

[image]

```
plt.imshow(im, interpolation = 'none', vmin = 50, vmax = 250)
```

[image]

Seems to me the change of the parameters didn't show differences. Something wrong about the setting?

Comment: In principle the image you have is much better than the one you desire because you have a higher resolution. If instead you want to artificially blur your image, you can use other [interpolation settings](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/interpolation_methods.html). Or you smoothen the image prior to plotting. You can alternatively plot a `contourf` plot, and select the desired number of color levels yourself.

Comment: You may also decrease dynamic range via the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters.  Finally note, that [there are reasons](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#colormap) to use a different colormap.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Thank you for your great advice. I've found that simply toggling `vmin` and `vmax` can achieve my desired outcome. However, I still don't understand the use of `interpolation`.  Please see my edited post.

Comment: You can of course smooth in x and y.  How you decide to do that depends a good bit on your data

Comment: @JodyKlymak Thanks. By "smoothing" do you have any recommended practices?

Comment: For simple plot smoothing, a 1-d of 2-d convolve works good.  You can convolve with a top hat or a triangle, or whatever you want.  I use numpy.convolve usually https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17595912/gaussian-smoothing-an-image-in-python